# Mail app is slow/unresponsive under macOS Mojave. What can I do?

Tags: mail.app, mojave

After installing the public beta of macOS Mojave, the Mail app became slow/unresponsive.

I have already restarted the system. It did not help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I chose "Mailbox" - "Rebuild", the problem was immediately solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check Mail -> Preferences -> Rules. See thousands of duplicate rules?
If so, select all duplicates (shift-click), then hit Remove button.
Patience - takes awhile to remove them.
Quit Mail app, then reopen.
Faster?